# Parse server rest password receiving email problem

Tags: node.js, flutter, parse-server

I'm trying to implement the rest Password in my application so to do that I have added an email adapter to my server, like:

```
var parseServer = new ParseServer({
    ...
    verifyUserEmails: false, 
    emailVerifyTokenValidityDuration: 24 * 60 * 60,
    preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail: false,
    emailAdapter: !hasSMTPInfo ? undefined : {
        module: 'parse-smtp-template',
        options: {
            port: env.EMAIL_PORT,
            host: env.EMAIL_HOST,
            user: env.EMAIL_USER,
            password: env.EMAIL_PASSWORD,
            fromAddress: env.EMAIL_FROMADDRESS,
            template: false,
            templatePath: env.EMAIL_TEMPLATEPATH
        }
    },
```

Rq: I have used the documentation of parse server api email from [documentation][1]

then I have implement the code of flutter part like:

```
    final user = User(null, null, email);
     await user.requestPasswordReset().then((value) async {
       print(value.statusCode);
       AlertUtils.showSuccessDialog('Veuillez vérifier votre boîte de réception')
           .then((_) => Get.toNamed('/login'));
     }).catchError((err) {
       onDone.call();
       AlertUtils.showErrorDialog(err.message.toString());
     });
```

my problem is the status of response is 200 so every thing are right but I can't get any emails of restarting pw.
[1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-smtp-template

Comment: Do you see anything helpful on your logs? Is the port open on your server out?

Comment: nope.... Just I can see the ordinary logs

Comment: I'd try to either use a different mail adapter or dry to debug this one. You may find some error being thrown on the process.